# How to add 2 ip addresses to a LAN interface using batch file

Tags: networking, ip, cmd.exe

How can I add 2 ip addresses to a single interface using CMD. So, I can run it as a batch file.

Comment: Use [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)

Comment: i know its done by netsh... I tried this
    netsh int ip set address "LAN" static 192.168.0.99 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
and for another address, in 2nd line I used 'ip add address' instead of 'ip set address' but it doesnt work